# How to use snow_record succesfully?

Tags: python, ansible, python-module

Does anyone try snow_record in ansible 2.5 ? When I try to run:

```
---
- name: executue sth
  hosts: localhost
  connection: local
  gather_facts: no
  ignore_errors: True
  tasks:

    - name: update an incident
      snow_record:
        username: test
        password: test2
        instance: dev9999
        state: present
        number: CHG0064887
        data:
          work_notes : "Been working all day on this thing."
```

I am getting error:

```
{
    "_ansible_parsed": false,
    "_ansible_no_log": false,
    "module_stderr": "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pysnow/client.py:129: DeprecationWarning: `query` is deprecated and will be removed in a future release. Please use `resource()` instead.\n  \"Please use `resource()` instead.\" % inspect.stack()[1][3], DeprecationWarning)\nTraceback (most recent call last):\n  File \"/tmp/ansible_XM2VJD/ansible_module_snow_record.py\", line 331, in <module>\n    main()\n  File \"/tmp/ansible_XM2VJD/ansible_module_snow_record.py\", line 328, in main\n    run_module()\n  File \"/tmp/ansible_XM2VJD/ansible_module_snow_record.py\", line 317, in run_module\n    except pysnow.UnexpectedResponse as e:\nAttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'UnexpectedResponse'\n",
    "changed": false,
    "module_stdout": "",
    "rc": 1,
    "msg": "MODULE FAILURE"
}
```

BTW, I had to install pysnow  by myself I thought once I upgraded to ansible 2.5 all the requirements would be installed automatically.

Comment: No solution to provide, but that would worth to report the issue on ansible github.

as of curiosity how did you install pysnow and which version do you use ?

Comment: Hi, thanks for the recommendation I think that is the time to report it.here are the details of pysnow, i just installed it by yum
Name: pysnow
Version: 0.7.4

Answer (score 0, accepted):

after github report it turns out that if your instance name xyz.service-now.com you have to put xyz as instance name in your yaml file